# Updating Array Variable In Extending Template

Tags: templating, variable, array

I have a layout template:

```
{% set bodyClass = [] %}

<body class="{% for class in bodyClass %}{{ class }} {% endfor %}">
    {{ block('pageBody') }}
</body>
```

And a template that extends it:

```
{% extends 'layout' %}

{% set bodyClass = bodyClass|merge(['myclass']) %}

{% block pageBody %}
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, consequuntur!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

When I try to append to the `bodyClass` variable I get the error:

> Variable "bodyClass" does not exist.

However if I call the variable:

```
{% for class in bodyClass %}
  {{ class  }}
{% endfor %}
```

The template renders fine. Why can't I merge onto a variable that's been set in an extended template? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I’m not certain that parent template variables are in scope in children. https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only access the parent's variable, not modify it. You could however simply add another block specifically for the body class, like so:

Layout template:

```
<body class="{% block body_class %}default-class-1 default-class-2{% endblock %}">
    {{ block('pageBody') }}
</body>
```

Template that extends it:

```
{% extends 'layout' %}

{% block body_class %}{{ parent() }} myclass{% endblock %}

{% block pageBody %}
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, consequuntur!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Note the call to parent() that includes the default classes defined in the parent template.

Comment: Thanks. Not 100% ideal since I won't be able to control the spacing before and after the classes, but I guess it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I often just declare a second (optional) variable in each template, with the default classes set in a layout, and merged with any additional ones:

```
{# __layout/base.twig #}

{% set defaultBodyClasses = ['app'] %}
{# Use `default([])` to make this a non-mandatory assignment in your templates: #}
{% set bodyClasses = templateProvidedBodyClasses | default([]) | merge(defaultBodyClasses) %}

<body class="{{ bodyClasses | join(' ') }}">...</body>
```

…and then in a template, say rendering an Entry…

```
{# _pages/page.twig #}

{% extends '__layouts/base' %}

{% set templateProvidedBodyClasses = [
    'app--my-static-flag',
    "app--section-#{entry.section.handle}",
    "app--type-#{entry.type.handle}"
] %}
```

Hope this helps illuminate another option!